# SearchView appears/disappears

Tags: android, xml, searchview

In my application I'd like to create something like this:

[image: Gif1]

I want all the AppBar to appear / disappear but using CollapingToolbarLayout doesn't work for me.

I tried with something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

[...]

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

but it doesn't work.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Cheesesquare` demo to get what you want..

**Demo link :**

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

**Output :**

normal screen.

[image]

when scroll down screen it will hide `ToolBar`

[image]

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for, I'll try, thanks you

Comment: Sure, but please let me try it first :)