# I want to create a hidden view in android

Tags: android

[image]
http://sinwho.com/data/q1.jpg

I made a layout like the picture
When you scroll up, the view disappears, but when you scroll down, the view does not appear immediately.

Can I scroll up a little to make the view visible?

Can I make the view invisible at first startup and then make it visible when scrolled down?

Thank you

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:background="@drawable/search"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgb_search_cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/search_cancel"
                android:visibility="gone" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main.scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38390543/3145960

Comment: Reaz Murshed Thank you very much